# How I could replace and array element by array index in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, linux

I have an array like this I use

```
       inputx.scan(/.*?\n/)
```

for create array this is a representation of my array

```
      element 1 => [car;dog;soda]
       element 2 => [bunny;pc;laptop]
   element 3  => [hand;sword;shield]
```

this is my text file I use scan  method for create array      inputx.scan(/.*?\n/)

```
     car;dog;soda

       bunny;pc;laptop

     hand;sword;shield
```

I need to replace each comma by number of array for obtain this

**this is my expected output**

in this output I replace ";" by "nthelementnumber;" example **1;**

```
      car1;dog1;soda

        bunny2;pc2;laptop

       hand3;sword3;shield
```

Please help me

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what exactly your array looks like, but I'm going to take a guess:

```
element = ['car;dog;soda',
           'bunny;pc;laptop',
           'hand;sword;shield']
```

If that's correct, you can get  the output you are looking for with something like:

```
element.each_index {|i| element[i] = element[i].gsub(';', "#{i+1};")}
```

The `each_index` iterator gives you each index (unsurprisingly). Then you can use each index to manipulate each value in the array.

Comment: yes works very thank you help me to complete my code ; I am very gratefully :)